# MongoDB Driver Not Being Recognized

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building an express app that uses MongoDB for its back end but when I make a request to the database in other parts of the app it's not being recognized.

Here's what I have:

**APP.JS (Using Paul's Answer):**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

// make mongodb available to the application
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas', (e, db) => {
  if (e) return next(e);
  req.db = db;
  next();
});

// cleanup
  req.on('end', () => { req.db.close(); });
});

//define routes
var root = require('./routes/index');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var contact = require('./routes/contact');
var formula = require('./routes/formula');
var formulaAPI = require('./routes/api/formula');
var formulaList = require('./routes/formula-list');
var formulaListAPI = require('./routes/api/formula-list');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(root);
app.use(about);
app.use(contact);
app.use(formula);
app.use(formulaAPI);
app.use(formulaList);
app.use(formulaListAPI);
app.use(authenticate);

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("The server is now listening on port 3000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I call the database through a route like this:

```
var app = require('express');
var router = app.Router();
var data = require('../data/formula.json');

router.get('/formula-list', function(req, res){
var db = req.db;
db.formulas.find({}, {}, function(e, docs){
  res.render('formula-list', {
    formulas: docs,
    title: 'Your Formulas',
    description: `List of saved user formulas from the formula generator`,
    ID: 'formula-list',
    keywords: 'formula generator, health kismet, nutraceutical formula 
  builder'
  });
});
});
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

When I do a `console.log(req.db)` I get the following in my console:

**req.db:**

```
EventEmitter {
domain: null,
_events: {},
_eventsCount: 0,
_maxListeners: undefined,
s:
 { databaseName: 'formulas',
 dbCache: {},
 children: [],
 topology:
  EventEmitter {
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    clientInfo: [Object],
    s: [Object] },
 options:
  { readPreference: [Object],
    promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] },
 logger: { className: 'Db' },
 bson: {},
 authSource: undefined,
 readPreference:
  { _type: 'ReadPreference',
    mode: 'primary',
    tags: undefined,
    options: undefined },
 bufferMaxEntries: -1,
 parentDb: null,
 pkFactory: undefined,
 nativeParser: undefined,
 promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
 noListener: false,
 readConcern: undefined },
 serverConfig: [Getter],
 bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
 databaseName: [Getter] }
```

Comment: Can you show the middleware that attaches the mongoclient instance to the request?

Comment: @Paul - maybe you just touched on the issue, because there isn't any.  I assumed that wrapping up the driver in the `app` export would be enough so long as I included it in the parts of the app where I needed to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the [documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#find-all-documents), I can see that to access a particular collection, this is what you have to do:

1. Select the collection on which you want to perform the operation
2. Perform the operation

Here is the code example:

```
router.get('/formula-list', function(req, res) {

  // Select the collection on which you want to perform an operation
  var formulas = req.db.collection('formulas');

  // Perform that operation
  formulas.find({}, {}, function(e, docs) {

    res.render('formula-list', {
      formulas: docs,
      title: 'Your Formulas',
      description: `List of saved user formulas from the formula generator`,
      ID: 'formula-list',
      keywords: 'formula generator, health kismet, nutraceutical formula builder'
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, so before declaring the first route that needs the connection, you'll want to wire up your middleware to assign the db connection to the request.  Probably a good idea to release the resource again after the response is sent as well, unless you're using connection pooling.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas', (e, db) => {
    if (e) return next(e);
    req.db = db;
    next();
  });

  // cleanup
  req.on('end', () => { req.db.close(); });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I went ahead and made your changes and am still getting the same error.  I updated my `app.js` file in the question above to reflect what I have right now.  Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: What do you expect db.formulas to be?  I don't see that set anywhere.  The mongo cli and the mongo driver don't use the same syntax, I think what you're trying to do is something like req.db.collection('formulas').find().  That said, if `req.db` is undefined, then there's something else wrong.  What happens when  you console.log(req.db) in the middlewhere that you first use (the one with the mongo.connect call)?

Comment: `formulas` is a mongodb collection that's already been populated with a few documents.  I started using monk for  this project, but switched to plain MongoDB so I could learn the database better, hence the problems with the driver.  I updated the question above to include the contents of `console.log(req.db)`

Comment: Like I said, you can't call req.db.formulas.  Check out the driver API, it needs to be req.db.collection('formulas ')

Answer (score 3):

Try using it like this

```
db.collection('collectionName').find({}).toArray(function(e, docs){
  res.render('formula-list', {
    formulas: docs,
    title: 'Your Formulas',
    description: `List of saved user formulas from the formula generator`,
    ID: 'formula-list',
    keywords: 'formula generator, health kismet, nutraceutical formula 
  builder'
  });
```

});

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your db init code up (before your routes definition) and add a middleware that includes the mongodb driver into the req object. Something like:

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas', function(err, db){
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        req.db = db;
        next();
    });
});

app.use(root); ...
```

Comment: This could lead to some problems, as you're continuing to mount handlers and spin up the app while waiting for the connection to complete.  `app.use` order matters, and so this is very likely to result in `req.db` being available non-deterministically on routes, depending on how long the connection takes.  Further, I believe it'll result in one connection for all requests, which will be a performance impact as well.

Answer (score 1):

`db.formulas` does not exist, this is a short hand from the mongo REPL.

In Node.js you need to first get the collection using

`db.collection('name')`

This means instead of doing `db.formulas.find` you can do:

`db.collection('formulas').find({}, {}, function(e, docs){})`

You could alternatively do:

`db.formulas = db.collection('formulas');
 db.another = db.collection('another');`

However it is always best to not add in "magic code"